# How can I determine that there is a network congestion or not ? or How to make congestion in a V2V and V2I network?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I've run SUMO 0.30.0 , with Veins 5.0 and OMNET++ 4.7 with the existing example, I want to make sure that the network is congested, or make the network be congested.
Then I want to measure bandwidth and total packets (WSMs, WSAs, BSM, ACk., ... etc) during the simulation.
I cannot find either the bandwidth of the network or the number of total packets?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by either increasing the number of nodes or by increasing the frequency of packet injection in network. Look out for the simulation results files after running the experiment. They have the required simulation parameters related to network congestion